# Separate string into list in r

Tags: r, string, list, parsing, character

I have a string in R that looks like this:

```
"{[PP]}{[BGH]}{[AC]}{[ETL]}....{[D]}"
```

I want to convert it into a list so that:

```
List[[1]] = {[PP]}
List[[2]] = {[BGH]}
....
List[[N]] = {[D]}
```

If there were commas you could do strsplit but I want to keep the brackets and not get rid of them. Not sure how to do this in R

Answer (score 3):

without regular expressions:

```
s <- "{[PP]}{[BGH]}{[AC]}{[ETL]}{[D]}"
as.list(paste("{", strsplit(s, "\\{")[[1]][-1], sep = ""))
[[1]]
[1] "{[PP]}"

[[2]]
[1] "{[BGH]}"

[[3]]
[1] "{[AC]}"

[[4]]
[1] "{[ETL]}"

[[5]]
[1] "{[D]}"
```

Comment: Apart from that `\\{` , which is a regular expression, which you can avoid with `fixed=TRUE` and `sep="{"` if you want. You might also benefit from reversing it to split on `}` like `paste0(strsplit(s,"}",fixed=TRUE)[[1]],"}")`

Comment: How would you recommend doing it if each element starts with {\ and ends with }]}]}

Answer (score 2):

`strsplit` still works if you pass this regular expression `(?<=})(?={)` which constrains the position to split on:

```
strsplit(s, "(?<=})(?={)", perl = T)

# [[1]]
# [1] "{[PP]}"  "{[BGH]}" "{[AC]}"  "{[ETL]}" "{[D]}"
```

Or as @thelatemail suggested:

```
strsplit(s, "(?<=})", perl = T)
```

Comment: Is there any reason why `strsplit(x, "(?<=})", perl=TRUE)` wouldn't be sufficient?

Comment: @thelatemail Not really. I think that's actually a better answer.

Comment: How would you recommend doing it if each element starts with {\ and ends with }]}]}

Comment: Can you give an example? It's hard to think what you have based on your description.

Comment: [1] "{\"suspect\": {\"duration\": 27.963592529296875, \"legOne\": {\"timestamp\": \"20110630235032921774\", \"side\": \"Offer\", \"price\": 131500.0, \"deltaCt\": 1, \"deltaSz\": 100, \"level\": 1, \"fixId\": 8327571}, \"legTwo\": {\"timestamp\": \"20110630235100885324\", \"side\": \"Offer\", \"price\": 131500.0, \"deltaCt\": -1, \"deltaSz\": -100, \"level\": 1, \"fixId\": 8327652}}, \"trade_hist\": [{\"price\": 131500.0, \"timestamp\":...... \"orders\": 43}]}]}"

Comment: There is a lot of data so I excluded it in between

Comment: This is a Json string. Check 'rjson' or 'jsonlite' package which has the 'fromJSON()' for your problem. You don't need to manually split it.

Comment: Yeah the file is in the json format but I am reading it in as a string using readChar because I just need the info in the string format when I place it into the list. Right now I have a program that works with 1 of these elements I just need to add a line that can make the program run for multiple elements.

Just one element looks like "{\"suspect".......}]}]}"
While multiple elements looks like "{\"suspect".......}]}]}{\"suspect".......}]}]}{\"suspect".......}]}]}....{\"suspect".......}]}]}"

Comment: Try `(?<=}\\]}\\]})` as the split. `strsplit("{\"suspect\".......}]}]}{\"suspect\".......}]}]}{\"suspect\".......}]}]}....{\"suspect\".......}]}]}", "(?<=}\\]}\\]})", perl = T)`

Answer (score 0):

obligatory `stringi` answer:

```
library(stringi)

dat <- "{[PP]}{[BGH]}{[AC]}{[ETL]}{[more]{[D]}"
as.list(stri_match_all_regex(dat, "(\\{\\[[[:alpha:]]+\\]\\})")[[1]][,2])
## [[1]]
## [1] "{[PP]}"
## 
## [[2]]
## [1] "{[BGH]}"
## 
## [[3]]
## [1] "{[AC]}"
## 
## [[4]]
## [1] "{[ETL]}"
## 
## [[5]]
## [1] "{[D]}"
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a convenient function in `qdap` for this i.e. `bracketXtract`

```
library(qdap)
setNames(as.list(bracketXtract(s, "curly", TRUE)), NULL)
#[[1]]
#[1] "{[PP]}"

#[[2]]
#[1] "{[BGH]}"

#[[3]]
#[1] "{[AC]}"

#[[4]]
#[1] "{[ETL]}"

#[[5]]
#[1] "{[D]}"
```

By default, `with = FALSE`.  So without using `with = TRUE`, it will remove the bracket.

#### data

```
s <- "{[PP]}{[BGH]}{[AC]}{[ETL]}{[D]}"
```